# Need to make nested json in haskell

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

At the first time my code worked but without this code :

```
"decisions" .= object ["texts" .= texts,
                                                                              "liens" .= liens]
```

And when I try to make a nasted json how you can see in my next code that not worked:

```
data Decisions = Decisions { texts :: Text,
                             liens :: Int
                 } 
                  deriving Show

data Chap = Chap { titre :: String,
                   image :: String,
                   paragraph :: [Text],
                   decisione :: [Text],
                   link :: [Int],                  
                   battle :: [Text],
                   decisions :: [Decisions]
                 } 
                  deriving Show


instance ToJSON Chap where
     toJSON (Chap titre image paragraph decisione link battle decisions) = object [
                                       "titre" .= titre,
                                       "image" .= image,
                                       "paragraph" .= array paragraph, 
                                       "decisione" .= array decisione,
                                       "link" .= array link,                                       
                                       "battle" .= array battle,
                                       "decisions" .= object ["texts" .= texts,
                                                              "liens" .= liens]                                    
                                       ]

getServiceR :: Int -> Handler Value
getServiceR id  = do 
     returnJson $ extraire $ find (condition id) chapitres
     where
       condition id (idChap, chap) = id == idChap

       extraire Nothing = Chap "" "" [] [] [] [] [[],[]]
       extraire (Just (id,p)) = p


chapitres :: [(Int, Chap)]
chapitres = [
             (1,Chap "Titre 1" "image 1" ["paragraph1", "paragraph11"] ["decisione 1"] [125] ["yes"] [(["turn left"],["5"]) (["turn right"],["15"])]),
             (2,Chap "Titre 2" "image 2" ["paragraph2", "paragraph21"] ["decisione 2"] [125] ["yes"] [["turn left"],["35"]] (["turn right"],["105"])]),
             (3,Chap "Titre 3" "image 3" ["paragraph1", "paragraph11"] ["decisione 1"] [125] ["yes"] [["turn left"],["55"]] ([],[])]),  
        ]
```

Error which i recive :

```
Handler\Game.hs:130:758:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a15] -> Decisions'
                with actual type `[a14]'
    The function `[]' is applied to one argument,
    but its type `[a14]' has none
    In the expression: [] []
    In the 7th argument of `Chap', namely `[[] []]'
Build failure, pausing...
```

Please I need to know a right syntaxe to make the nested jeson in haskell.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo on line 130. It looks like you wanted to write `[[], []]` but accidentally wrote `[[] []]` instead.

Comment: Have you tried to use [deriveToJSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson/docs/Data-Aeson-TH.html#v:deriveToJSON)?

Answer (score 1):

The 7th argument of the `Chap` type is `[Decisions]` and each `Decisions` is made up of `Text Int`.

There are two important things:

- The way `Chap` declarations are used to create new instances
- Creating the ToJSON instance for `Chap`

For nested `ToJSON` types you must define an instance for each type used within. So if you're defining the ToJSON for `Chap` define the ToJSON for `Decisions` first, and the rest will work automatically.

The code sample below compiles successfully. I hope both points are clear enough.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson

data Decisions = Decisions { texts :: Text,
                             liens :: Int 
                 }   
                  deriving Show

data Chap = Chap { titre :: String,
                   image :: String,
                   paragraph :: [Text],
                   decisione :: [Text],
                   link :: [Int],                      
                   battle :: [Text],
                   decisions :: [Decisions]
                 }   
                  deriving Show


instance ToJSON Chap where
     toJSON (Chap titre image paragraph decisione link battle decisions) = object [
                                       "titre" .= titre,
                                       "image" .= image,
                                       "paragraph" .= paragraph, 
                                       "decisione" .= decisione,
                                       "link" .= link,                                           
                                       "battle" .= battle,
                                       "decisions" .= decisions 
                                       ]   
instance ToJSON Decisions where
    toJSON (Decisions texts liens) = object [ "texts" .= texts, "liens" .= liens ]

myChap = Chap "Titre 1" "image 1" ["paragraph1", "paragraph11"] ["decisione 1"] [125] ["yes"] [ (Decisions "turn left" 5),
                                                                                                (Decisions "turn left" 5)
                                                                                              ]
```

This code compiles. Loading it into ghci and running

```
> toJSON myChap
```

results in

```
Object fromList [("image",String "image 1"),("battle",Array (fromList [String "yes"])),("decisione",Array (fromList [String "decisione 1"])),("link",Array (fromList [Number 125])),("decisions",Array (fromList [Object fromList [("liens",Number 5),("texts",String "turn left")],Object fromList [("liens",Number 5),("texts",String "turn left")]])),("paragraph",Array (fromList [String "paragraph1",String "paragraph11"])),("titre",String "Titre 1")]
```